# angular $compile scope binding process

Tags: angularjs

All:

I am pretty new to angular directive, when I came across $compile, there is one confuse, say I have a directive:

```
<html ng-app="mainapp">
<body ng-controller="main">
</body>
</html>


    var app = angular.module("mainapp", []);
    app
    .controller("main", function($scope){

    })
    .directive("namearea", function(){
        return {
            restrict: "AE",
            scope: {
                conf: "="
            },
            template:"<div>{{conf.name}}</div>",
            link: function(){}
        }
    })
```

And by accident, someone(for example: I) uses an amazingly stupid way(just for curiosity) to add this directive like:

```
$compile( $("body").append("<namearea conf='conf'>") ) ($scope)
```

**The confuse here is: is that $scope used to set the scope which wraps namearea, or to replace the scope inside namearea?**

Thanks

Comment: It's the scope of the directive parent. In your use-case, it will be the object containing the `conf` property used in `conf='conf'`. The directive itself has an isolate scope.

Comment: @Phil Thanks, very clear.

Answer (score 1):

> The confuse here is: is that $scope used to set the scope which wraps namearea, or to replace the scope inside namearea?

The $scope that you pass in is the $scope in that namearea directive is generated. It'll can access this $scope properties

Ex:

```
$compile( $("body").append("<namearea conf='myvar'>") ) ($scope)
```

Then the namearea is able to access $scope.myvar in two way binding (as you declared). The namearea is isolated scope i'll not be replace by the $scope that you pass.